# objective-c code: parse and renaming programmatically - is it possible?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, parsing, obfuscation

I have objective-c project(ios library). I need to rename methods in my project. (it will be a small obfuscation). Are there any frameworks that allow you to do this programmatically? I tried to write my solution - but it turns out too complicated. there are several open source projects - but unfortunately they don't suit me:

-[ios-class-guard](https://github.com/Polidea/ios-class-guard)

-[PPiOS-Rename](https://github.com/Polidea/ios-class-guard)

I need something that can parse both interface and implementation.
I also found the opinion that the syntax of objective-c is very complicated and writing its parser is a bad idea.

any advice I will be grateful

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Finding and Refactoring Code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/finding-and-refactoring-code)

Comment: The only alternative to my knowledge is LLVM IR obfuscation, but it doesn't seems like what you are looking for (renaming methods in the project). What are you exact requirements? What exactly is wrong with the said solutions you've already found? Why don't you just use Xcode refactor if you want to rename the methods? is there some specific pattern you want to follow when obfuscating the source code?